# Unable to save Existing Lightning Components after Summer19 release sandboxes

Tags: lightning-aura-components, release, summer19

There is issue in saving lightning components. Lightning components which has controller(which is referring User's fields).

Error message are stating like - There is no such column "Email" on User entity; where as the running user is System administrator.

Let us know, if someone found root cause, or work around for the same.

---

Update: Added sample code to reproduce the same

Sample component:
SampleComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="SampleClass">
    Hello World
</aura:component>
```

SampleClass

```
public class SampleClass {

    public SampleClass(){
        User u = [select id, email, mobilephone from User where id=: UserInfo.getUserId()];
        System.debug('Email: ' + u.email);
    }

}
```

**Error message**

> Failed to save SampleComponent.cmp: Invalid definition for null:SampleClass: select id, email, mobilephone from User where ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:12 No such column 'email' on entity 'User'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.: Source

Comment: Can you add minimal required code to see how you are referring user object field by editing your question?

Comment: @sanketkumar - Added the same, you can try with version - 46

Comment: By any chance in your org do you have an apex class named as `User`?

Comment: @Raul - Nope there is no class named as "User" and it is on every sandbox(except the prod, since it is not upgraded yet).

Comment: @sanketkumar and raul  - Is is reproducing in your sandboxes(with version 46), or is it just my org?

Comment: Just reproduced, so strange

Comment: It may be related to this new Summer 19 feature https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_aura_improved_validation.htm?edition=&impact=

Comment: @EnricoMurru I doubt it, since we're not referring in component. Its plain Hello_World component. I might wrong to interpret it, however ideally it should not impact 45 or less versioned components.

Comment: You're right, but this is the only known feature released with summer that can impact somehow how components are being saved :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also experienced this same issue in one my of custom lightning component. Where it was throwing the error message - There is no such column "ContactId" on User entity;

After struggling the whole day I got a solution for this.

**It is just to recompile APEX Classes.**

**Steps to fix it:**

1. Login to Salesforce org
2. Go to setup.
3. Enter "Apex Classes" in the quick search. And then click "Apex Classes".
4. You will see "Compile all classes" link there, just go and press it.
5. Once it completes, go to the component and make the changes and save it. Now it should not show any error.

Comment: strangely, this worked. Not sure why this is required. But yes this worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile classes then it will work. When ever it doesn't save I compile all classes and i was able to save it. I suspect it might be due to summer 19 release patches.